# use a jquery/js module in angular component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I wanted use a jquery function that uses an external library inside my component so Ive added its library in angular.json

```
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/html5media.min.js",
              "src/plyr.min.js",
            ]
```

otherwise i even used this libraries as main index.html file

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5media/1.1.8/html5media.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.5.6/plyr.min.js"></script>
  </head>
```

then imported jquery function in my component

```
import * as $ from 'plyr';
```

as you can see on below link, this jquery function uses a class (Plyr) that should be refer to library link but when i serve my projects, see this error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jQuery'.

37         jQuery(function ($) {
           ~~~~~~
```

and an interesting, when i resave save component file, it works but inside terminal the error remains:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Plyr'.

35                 var player = new Plyr('#audio1', {
                                    ~~~~
```

the mentioned jquery file:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import `plyr`, install it using

`npm i plyr`

and then you can import it in your component using

`import Plyr from 'plyr';`.

Comment: i did it before and gave this error as well ```error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jQuery'    Cannot find name 'Plyr'.

```